# How use SpEL result as @Value key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

In my springboot application i want use @Value to read some configure,but this configure's used in many other methods,so i want define configure's key as a constant.This is the code:

```java
@Component
public class InstanceConfig {

    private static final String CONFIGURE_KEY = "SUPPORT_MANAGER_PLANE_INSTANCES";

    @Value("${SUPPORT_MANAGER_PLANE_INSTANCES}")
    private String supportManageInstances;
    
    @ApolloConfigChangeListener(value = ConfigConsts.NAMESPACE_APPLICATION)
    public void processConfigureChange(ConfigChangeEvent event) {
        log.info("configure changed do somthing");
        ConfigChange configChange = event.getChange("SUPPORT_MANAGER_PLANE_INSTANCES");
    }
}
```

In this code variable "SUPPORT_MANAGER_PLANE_INSTANCES" used by `@Value` and `processConfigureChange` method,if need to modify this variable's value i need modify all refer this variable,so i want define one constant variable `CONFIGURE_KEY` `@Value` and `processConfigureChange` method use this variable.

Comment: maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30597973/11640072

Comment: *used in many other methods* Please provide more details. There's likely an existing pattern to use depending on the specifics of your case.

Comment: Consider wrapping in an @Configuraton class so the value is injected within a single class.   Then inject the configuration class in the other classes which need to know about `namespace`.  The config class provides a simple getter method.

Comment: if we get CONFIGURE_KEY’s value from a function like public String getConfigureKey() how should we define @Value("???")？

Answer (score 1):

Thans @hirarqi's help

```java
@Component
public class InstanceConfig {

    private static final String CONFIGURE_KEY = "SUPPORT_MANAGER_PLANE_INSTANCES";

    @Value("${" + CONFIGURE_KEY + "}")
    private String supportManageInstances;
    
    @ApolloConfigChangeListener(value = ConfigConsts.NAMESPACE_APPLICATION)
    public void processConfigureChange(ConfigChangeEvent event) {
        log.info("configure changed do somthing");
        ConfigChange configChange = event.getChange(CONFIGURE_KEY);
    }
}
```